# Is it possible to display data by using method in angularjs without scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, methods

I have a method:

```
<span ng-init="getJobApplicantsList(jobId)">(number should be display here)</span>
```

is it possible to show data without storing that in to scope variable

because i am using this method in a lot of places.

And this is my controller:

```
var set = [blah,blah];//object
$scope.getJobApplicantsList = function(jobId) {
findByMatchingProperties(set, { jobId: jobId }).length; //i have a function and i'm getting number here Example:`250` int
}
```

i Want something like this:

```
 <span>{{getJobApplicantsList(jobId)}}</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the number

```
$scope.getJobApplicantsList = function(jobId) {
   return   findByMatchingProperties(set, { jobId: jobId }).length;  
}
```

and call the function in template

```
<span>{{getJobApplicantsList(jobId)}}</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return the value from the function and no need to store it into any scope variable.

You can also avoid usage of $scope by using -

JS -

```
var vm = this;
vm.getJobApplicantsList = function (jobId) {
            return findByMatchingProperties(set, { jobId: jobId }).length;
        }
```

HTML -

```
<div ng=controller="AppController as vm">
  <span ng-bind="vm.getJobApplicantsList(jobId)"></span>
</div>
```